# Flex: Inline Component is not defined?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I opened up FB3 today, without making any changes, I press F11 and now I am getting this error that I never have gotten before:

**ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable CaratPicker2_inlineComponent1 is not defined.**

I find it strange I am getting this error everytime now, when I never got it before and I didn't make any changes before I started getting it.

Anyways it is coming from line 78 which is `<mx:Component>` the start of an inline item renderer.

So any ideas how or why this error is being thrown? I have never seen an error like this before and the message isn't very clear to me as to what the issue is.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with Flex Builder upper menu -> Project -> Clean...

It looks like there are problems with the generated actionscript code. The mxml components get "translated" to .as files by the compiler but, for efficiency, it tries to keep them for as long as possible instead of generating them again each time.

Comment: That fixed it, and thank you very much, I had no idea about this feature! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this inline component not defined error, too.
But my problem is there are two mxml documents with the same name in the project(not in the same package)

so the solution is change the file name and make sure all mxml files have different name.